# Launch and intent request at the same time?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, alexa-skills-kit

How do I invoke an intent at the same time as launching the skill. Is special code handling required, the documentation makes out like amazon handles this and just passes the IntentRequest? The example below is not invoking the skill at all when an intent is used at the same time as launch. Anyone have any ideas?

[image: Example]

p.s this is my first Alexa skill so please go easy on me!

Thanks,
Sean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't require any special code for it to immediately pick up an IntentRequest.

In my experience though, it can be a little buggy, especially in the developer console test simulator.

The first thing to try might be to add "to get help" (rather than just "get help") to your sample utterances (and remember to rebuild the model). Although officially, "to" is one of the [connecting words](https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/custom-skills/understanding-how-users-invoke-custom-skills.html) including it in the sample utterance could help when trying to invoke the intent immediately. Similarly, you could see if "ask control discord get help" (so omitting "to") works.

The second thing to try is maybe using it on an Alexa device or in the Alexa mobile app.

Comment: Adding the 'to' in the sample utterances fixed it, thank you so much.